# Print colorized output - working from console but not from script

Tags: python, windows, console

I have weird problem that I cannot put my finger on. There is a program that I use (and contribute from time to time) that has colorized console output. Everything worked great until I reinstalled Windows. Now I cannot get colorized output.

This is the [script](https://bitbucket.org/alefnula/tea/src/dc14009a19d66f92463549332a321b29c71d47b8/src/tea/console/color.py?at=default) that is used for colorizing.

I have managed to narrow down the problem to, more or less, simple situation, but I have no idea what is wrong.

This is console prompt that works as expected (string `test` is printed in red):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, r'c:\bin\SV\tea\src')
>>> from tea.console.color import cprint, Color
>>> cprint('test\n', Color.red)
test
>>>
```

But when I run following script with same version of python I get output `test` but not in red color (there is no color, just default console color):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'c:\bin\SV\tea\src')

from tea.console.color import cprint, Color
cprint('test\n', Color.red)
```

- The same setup worked before I reinstalled my system.
- I have checked, environment variables in interactive mode and script are the same.
- I have tried this in standard windows command prompt and Console, program that I 
  usually use.
- OS in question is Windows 8 and before reinstall this was also used on Windows 8.
- Same code with same setup works at computer at work (Windows 7).
- I have Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 installed (as I did before). I have tried to run script 
  with calling python interpreter directly (`c:\Python27\python.exe`) or with `py -2`,
  but it does not help.
- IPython and mercurial colorizes output as it should.

Any ideas what can I try to make this work?

**Edit**:

Maybe it was not clear, but script I use to colorize output is given in a link in question. Here it is once again: 
https://bitbucket.org/alefnula/tea/src/dc14009a19d66f92463549332a321b29c71d47b8/src/tea/console/color.py?at=default

Comment: Can you share the code to `tea.console.color`? Is it doing any terminal detection to disable colors when used in the context of a pipe, for example?

Comment: There is a link to tea.console.color in question. I will edit question to make it more clear.

Comment: Looking at the [utils module source code](https://bitbucket.org/alefnula/tea/src/dc14009a19d6/src/tea/system/__init__.py?at=default) I wondering *why* the project doesn't use the [`platform`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html) module? It is entirely possible the platform detection goes wrong somewhere.

Comment: Maybe, but I traced it and code in branch `platform.is_a(platform.WINDOWS | platform.DOTNET)` is executed on my system. Not sure whay platform module was not used, I am not the author, but current code worked and still works on other computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the problem and solution.

I believe that the problem was the bug in x64 ctypes module. I had Python 2.7 x64 installed and with that version following line (from script that I linked in question):

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTextAttribute(std_out_handle, code)
```

returns error code 6 with description `The handle is invalid`. After some investigation, I deduced that problem might be x64 version of python, so I installed 32-bit version and everything works as expected.

Since this solves my problem, and I do not have the time for deeper analysis I will leave it at this, just wanted to give some kind of resolution for question.